# Rotate - Resize JQuery Mobile (touch)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, resize, touch, rotation

Is there any way to rotate-resize a div by using touch gestures for both android and iphone? I found this http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/photofun/  basically you put both your fingers on the screen to rotate and resize and one just to drag. But I can't get this one working in my JQuery code. Is there any existing plugin perhaps? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery Plugin that can be used to do the thing you need... It is build to work on an iPad and based on touch commands, so when looking at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5sTEh/ I recommend using a touch device of some kind to see the demonstration. Hope this helps.

```
;(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var undef, zindex = 400, propNameTransform = 'Transform', propNameTransformOrigin = 'TransformOrigin', transformProps = [
        'O',
        'ms',
        'Webkit',
        'Moz'
    ], i = transformProps.length, div = document.createElement('div'), divStyle = div.style;

    while(i--) {
        if((transformProps[i]+propNameTransform) in divStyle) {
            propNameTransform = transformProps[i]+propNameTransform;
            propNameTransformOrigin = transformProps[i]+propNameTransformOrigin;
        }
    }

    function getRotationAngle(touch1X, touch1Y, touch2X, touch2Y) {
        var x = touch1X - touch2X,
            y = touch1Y - touch2Y,
            radiant = Math.atan2(y, x);

        return (radiant * 180 / Math.PI);   
    }

    $.fn.TouchBox = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            drag: false,
            resize: false,
            rotate: false,
            callback_touches: null,
            callback_size_change: null,
            callback_position_change: null,
            callback_degree_change: null
        }

        if(options != undef) $.extend(defaults, options);

        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                touches = 0,
                diffX = 0,
                diffY = 0,
                startWidth = 0,
                startHeight = 0,
                startDistance = 0,
                ignoreTouch = false,
                startX = 0,
                startY = 0,
                rotatePoint1X = 0,
                rotatePoint1Y = 0,
                rotatePoint2X = 0,
                rotatePoint2Y = 0,
                rotation = false,
                startDegree = 0,
                currDegree = 0,
                _startDegree = 0;

            if(defaults.rotate) this.style[propNameTransformOrigin] = 'center center';

            $this.bind('touchstart', function (e) {
                zindex += 1;

                $this.css({ zIndex: zindex });

                touches = e.originalEvent.touches.length;

                if(ignoreTouch) ignoreTouch = false;

                if(!ignoreTouch) {
                    var offsetLeft = parseFloat($this.css('left'),10),
                        offsetTop = parseFloat($this.css('top'),10),
                        x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
                        y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

                    startX = offsetLeft;
                    startY = offsetTop;

                    diffX = x - offsetLeft;
                    diffY = y - offsetTop;
                }

                if(defaults.rotate) {
                    if(touches == 1) {
                        rotatePoint1X = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                        rotatePoint1Y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                    } else if(touches == 2) {
                        rotatePoint2X = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageX;
                        rotatePoint2Y = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageY;

                        startDegree = getRotationAngle(rotatePoint1X, rotatePoint1Y, rotatePoint2X, rotatePoint2Y);
                        _startDegree = currDegree;

                        rotation = true;
                    }
                }

                if(defaults.resize && touches == 2) {
                    startWidth = $this.width();
                    startHeight = $this.height();
                    var x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
                        y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
                        x2 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageX,
                        y2 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageY,
                        xd = x2 - x,
                        yd = y2 - y,
                        distance = Math.sqrt(xd*xd + yd*yd);

                    startDistance = distance;
                }
            }).bind('touchmove', function (e) {
                if(defaults.callback_touches != null) defaults.callback_touches.apply(this, [touches]);

                if(defaults.resize && touches == 2) {
                    var x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
                        y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
                        x2 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageX,
                        y2 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageY,
                        xd = x2 - x,
                        yd = y2 - y,
                        distance = Math.sqrt(xd*xd + yd*yd),
                        halfDistance = ((distance - startDistance)/2),
                        newWidth = (startWidth + (distance - startDistance)),
                        newHeight = (startHeight + (distance - startDistance)),
                        newLeft = (startX-halfDistance),
                        newTop = (startY-halfDistance);

                    $this.css({
                        width: newWidth+'px',
                        height: newHeight+'px',
                        left: newLeft+'px',
                        top: newTop+'px'
                    });

                    if(defaults.callback_size_change != null) defaults.callback_size_change.apply(this, [newWidth, newHeight]);
                    if(defaults.callback_position_change != null) defaults.callback_position_change.apply(this, [newLeft, newTop]);
                }

                if(defaults.drag && !ignoreTouch && (touches == 2 || touches == 1)) {
                    var x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
                        y = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
                        newLeft = (x-diffX),
                        newTop = (y-diffY);

                    $this.css({
                        left: newLeft+'px',
                        top: newTop+'px'
                    });

                    if(defaults.callback_position_change != null) defaults.callback_position_change.apply(this, [newLeft, newTop]);
                }

                if(defaults.rotate && rotation) {
                    var lastDegrees = currDegree,
                    degrees = (startDegree - getRotationAngle(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY, e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageY) - _startDegree) * -1;
                    currDegree = degrees;
                    this.style[propNameTransform] = 'rotate('+Math.floor(degrees)+'deg)';

                    if(defaults.callback_degree_change != null) defaults.callback_degree_change.apply(this, [lastDegrees, degrees]);
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            }).bind('touchend', function (e) {
                touches -= 1;

                if(touches == 1) ignoreTouch = true;

                rotation = false;

                if(defaults.callback_touches != null) defaults.callback_touches.apply(this, [touches]);
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $boxes = $('.touch-box');

        if($boxes.length > 0) {
            $boxes.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    options = {
                        'drag': false,
                        'resize': false,
                        'rotate': false
                    },
                    resize = $this.attr('data-resize'),
                    drag = $this.attr('data-drag'),
                    rotate = $this.attr('data-rotate');

                if(resize != undef && resize == 'true') options['resize'] = true;
                if(drag != undef && drag == 'true') options['drag'] = true;
                if(rotate != undef && rotate == 'true') options['rotate'] = true;

                $this.TouchBox(options);
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```